# Mongo aggregate $match and $group in $lookup result

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

**I have node text**
I have 3 models lead, user and company
I want to get all customers for selected company id using lead model
what I try was,
using $lookup and $group I got unique customer with details but after adding $match I got empty array
I hope someone can get my on the right track..

****This is my Aggregation code ****

```
const customers = await Lead.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { moving_company: companyId }, 
  },
 
  {
  $group: {
    _id: {
        "customer": "$customer",
        
    },
  }
},
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "_id.customer",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "myCustomResut",
    },
  },


]);
```

****This is my Company model****

```
  const schemaOptions: mongoose.SchemaOptions = {
  _id: true,
  id: false,
  timestamps: true,
  skipVersioning: true,
  strict: false,
  toJSON: {
    getters: true,
    virtuals: true,
  },
};

export const CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: Schema.Types.String,
    },
  },
  schemaOptions
);

const Company = mongoose.model<ICompany>("Company", CompanySchema);
export default Company;
```

**This my lead model**

```
    const schemaOptions: mongoose.SchemaOptions = {
  _id: true,
  id: false,
  timestamps: true,
  skipVersioning: true,
  strict: false,
  toJSON: {
    getters: true,
    virtuals: true,
  },
};

export const LeadSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    status: {
      type: Schema.Types.String,
    },
    customer: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: Customer.modelName
    },
    assigned_sales_agent: {
      type: Schema.Types.String,
      ref: Agent.modelName
    },
    moving_company: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref:Company.modelName
    },
    selected_categories: [
      {
        type: SelectedCategorySchema,
       
      },
    ],

  },
  schemaOptions
);

const Lead = mongoose.model<ILead>("Lead", LeadSchema);
export default Lead;
```

**This is my customer model**

```
export const customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
   
    address: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: Addresses,
    },
  },
  UserSchemaOptions
);

export const Customer = User.discriminator<ICustomer>(
  "Customer",
  customerSchema,
  Role.CUSTOMER
);

export default Customer;
```

Comment: Could you provide the aggregation query that you're trying to use?

Comment: `const customers = await Lead.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { moving_company: companyId }, 
  },
 
  {
  $group: {
    _id: {
        "customer": "$customer",
        
    },
  }
},
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "_id.customer",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "myCustomResut",
    },
  },


]);`